# Use same code on another button

Tags: c#, windows, button, text, tabpage

I'm using the exact same code multiple times and I thought that it would be quite inefficient to just copy/paste everything. Is there a way for let's say button2 to use the exact same code as button1 without copy/pasting everything?

Some of my code is very big, that's why I'm asking.

I'm aware of this for example:

```
    private TabPage T
    {
        get { return (t.SelectedTab); }
    }
```

However I have no idea how to make this work for this: (Yes, there are multiple ways to enable Full Screen mode in my application)

```
        if (FormBorderStyle != FormBorderStyle.None)
        {
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            p1.BackColor = Color.White;
            p2.BackColor = Color.White;
            TopMost = true;
            c2.Visible = false;
            Wi.Visible = false;
            t1.Visible = false;
            F.Text = "Exit Full Screen";
            t2.Text = "Exit Full Screen";
        }
        else
        {
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
            if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Build >= 7000)
            {
                if (DWM.DwmIsCompositionEnabled())
                {
                    Color c = Color.FromArgb(255, 221, 220, 220);
                    TransparencyKey = c;
                    p1.BackColor = c;
                    p2.BackColor = c;
                    MARGINS mr = new MARGINS();
                    mr.T = 1800;
                    IntPtr h = Handle;
                    int result = DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(h, ref mr);
                }
            }
            TopMost = false;
            Wi.Visible = true;
            t1.Visible = true;
            F.Text = "Full Screen";
            t2.Text = "Full Screen";
        }
```

Comment: You can move your code into a method. Have the button click events call that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply the same event handler to both buttons.  This can be done either through simply typing the name of the method in the events tab of the designer, or through manually adding the event handler upon construction.

It's generally a good idea in such cases to also refactor the method name into something that makes sense for both buttons to call.  If clicking `button2` fires `button1_click` some other coders might be confused.  If both buttons fire a `MakeFullscreen` method then it's less confusing.

Comment: I tried to use this: t2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.f); However the action performs noticeably slower?!?

Comment: Note that if you assign the same event handler to multiple controls, the designer will screw up and the event subscriptions will be lost at some random point in the future. Also, renaming the event handler to use a non-event handler naming is something I wouldn't recommend. A cleaner approach (which leads to better architecture) is to move the business logic into another method and just call that from both event handlers.

Comment: @JasonWilliams If you modify the auto generated designer file that would cause problems.  If you use the UI of the designer itself, and it's events menu, then no, it won't screw anything up at all.  As to whether you have two event handlers calling a method vs one method assigned as the handler to two events, that's mostly a convention.  Personally I consider the pattern you described as an indication of a lack of understanding as to what an event handler really is.  It's just a method.  It's no more special than any other method.  `button1_click` isn't *special* in any way.

Comment: @Servy: If you assign two controls to the same event handler using the forms designer, it _will_ lose the event subscriptions at some point in the future. I've seen this in VS 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012 (I like to share a single event handler for multiple controls, but every time I do it, I get burned within a few weeks when a subscription vanishes after making another edit on the form). As for corrupting naming conventions, I am surprised that someone with your rep would suggest putting shared business logic directly in an event handler rather than encapsulating it in a shared method.

Comment: @JasonWilliams As to the subscriptions vanishing, I rarely use the designer for that, I tend to subscribe to my events explicitly, so I don't run into the issue myself, but I've also never heard of it happening to anyone, and I find it highly surprising.  I'd suggest submitting a bug report to the VS team if you're able to create a reproducible example of it.  As to the other comment, your statement itself is differentiating an event handler from any other method.  *There is no such distinction*.  Event handlers are just methods, no more.  There is nothing special about them.

Comment: @Servy: Not having heard of something does not mean it is untrue. I made no such distinction about event _handlers_, only about event handler _naming_. (Yes, technically an event handler is just a delegate and any compatible delegate can be subscribed to an event, but if you use an unclear naming style readers of your code might not realise that your method is being _used_ as an event handler. I was voicing a commonly held _opinion_ that it is cleaner to move the shared logic into a separate method than to hack the name into an unconventional and possibly confusing form.

Answer (score 1):

You can also put the code in a separate method and call the method in both event handlers making no confusion about that it does and for who. they can see exactly which button calls what method or code. In this case it would be the same method.